# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.omnifaces.config.WebXml

Tags: jsf, omnifaces

I have added recently added omnifaces 1.4.1 to my pom to use some of the converters.

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>omnifaces</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Now, every request to the application throws an exception which starts at

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.omnifaces.config.WebXml
```

The omnifaces.SelectItemsIndexConverter I'm using is working fine, but this exception is being thrown for every request; even on pages that do not contain [onmifaces](/questions/tagged/onmifaces) components.

My environment is as follows:

- Tomcat 7.0.37
- Mojarra 2.1.10
- PrimeFaces 3.4.2
- PrimeFaces Extensions 0.6.1

Is there some additional setup that is required more than just adding to the pom?

```
Apr 18, 2013 11:35:06 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/MyApp] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.omnifaces.config.WebXml
    at org.omnifaces.context.OmniPartialViewContext$OmniPartialResponseWriter.startDocument(OmniPartialViewContext.java:253)
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialResponseWriter.startDocument(PrimePartialResponseWriter.java:133)
    at com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handlePartialResponseError(AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.java:199)
    at com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handle(AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.java:123)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:119)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:146)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Normally for NoClassDefFoundError, I found there is something messed up in my build path. You may want to look through your build path to make sure you have everything set properly there.

Comment: Is there no other exception in the log? The `WebXml` should throw a runtime exception if `web.xml` cannot be parsed. Put a breakpoint at line 144 of `WebXml` to check it.

Comment: I have confirmed that omnifaces-1.4.1.jar is in the WEB-INF/lib folder of the tomcat server. Not sure of what else to check for.

Comment: After adding the breakpoint, the debugger showed this exception:  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: avax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException

Comment: Apparently you've an error page on exception type of `avax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException` instead of the intented `javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException` declared in `web.xml`. But is that `ClassNotFoundException` really not been logged as such?

Comment: Yep... you nailed it.  The class in web.xml was missing the 'j'. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Great. I reposted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.omnifaces.config.WebXml

This will occur when [the `WebXml` configuration enum](http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/current/org/omnifaces/config/WebXml.html) failed to parse the webapp's `web.xml` and/or `web-fragment.xml`(s) during its initialization. This should however have thrown a runtime exception about that. I will check why it's been swallowed. It's perhaps Tomcat specific.

As to the runtime exception being thrown in your particular case,

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: avax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException

This suggests that you've in your `web.xml` something like:

```xml
<error-page>
    <exception-type>avax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
    ...
</error-page>
```

while it should really have been [`javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/ViewExpiredException.html). Fix it accordingly and `WebXml` will then succeed in parsing the `web.xml`.

Comment: I could reproduce the `ClassNotFoundException` being swallowed in Tomcat. I've added a `ServletContext#log()` line to make sure that the runtime exception is logged: https://code.google.com/p/omnifaces/issues/detail?id=169