# NoClassDefFoundException using Omnifaces 1.4/1.5 with jsf2 and primefaces

Tags: jsf, omnifaces

I saw a similar topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16088840/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-could-not-initialize-class-org-omnifaces-config) but the problem was not the same in my case.

I keep getting this when working with primefaces datatable ajax events:

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.omnifaces.config.WebXml
```

And the actions obviously don't work.

My environment is as follows:

My environment is as follows:

Glassfish 3.1.2
Mojarra 2.1.10
PrimeFaces 3.5
Omnifaces 1.5

My web.xml

```
 <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

<display-name>JavaServerFaces</display-name>  

<!-- Change to "Production" when you are ready to deploy -->
<context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
<param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- for EL 2.2-->
<context-param>
  <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
  <param-value>com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
</context-param>

  <context-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>
          /WEB-INF/security-context.xml
      </param-value>
  </context-param>
   <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
  <listener>
      <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <!-- Processes application requests -->
  <filter>
      <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
      <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

<error-page>
  <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
  <location>/login/login.jsf</location>
</error-page>

<context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
  <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- JSF mapping -->
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

 <!-- Map these files with JSF -->
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<mime-mapping>
  <extension>png</extension>
  <mime-type>image/png</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

Full stacktrace:

```
 javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=91;_ThreadName=http-thread-pool-80
 80(4);|StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.omnifaces.config.WebXml
    at org.omnifaces.context.OmniPartialViewContext$OmniPartialResponseWriter.startDocument(OmniPartialViewContext.java:253)
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialResponseWriter.startDocument(PrimePartialResponseWriter.java:133)
    at com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handlePartialResponseError(AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.java:199)
    at com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handle(AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.java:123)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:119)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I've tried changing to Omnifaces 1.1 and then this problem goes away, but using 1.4 and 1.5 gives this exception. The reason I need to use Omnifaces 1.4/1.5 is to get the h:inputSecret placeholder attribute. I'm not using omnifaces on the page that rises the exception.. Anybody got an idea where I've gone wrong, or have a solution to this?

Comment: In OmniFaces 1.5, the initialization fail should also be logged separately somewhere before this stacktrace. Didn't you see it in server startup logs? Usually, the only reasonable cause is a typo somewhere in `web.xml`, e.g. a wrong  `<exception-type>`, causing the `Class#forName()` on it to fail. If you can't find the log, it may be worth the effort to post the smallest possible `web.xml` contents which still reproduces this problem.

Comment: Hi, this is the only related Exception I beleive. The only other exception on startup is Exception while visiting org/bouncycastle/asn1/cmp/PKIStatusInfo.class.. I've posted web.xml.

Comment: This is really unfortunate. Your `web.xml` looks fine at first glance. Are you able to put a breakpoint in line 145 of `org.omnifaces.config.WebXml` of OmniFaces 1.5 and check if an exception is actually been thrown? Perhaps its logging failed or went to a different destination somehow.

Comment: I'm Using IntelliJ, so I downloaded the source and put a breakpoint at line 145 and deployed the application to the server in debug mode. Tried the datatable ajax actions. Seems that I never reached the breakpoint...

Comment: Weird. Is the constructor or `init()` invoked at all?

Comment: No, seems it never enters the init method, or the class at all. I went back to OmniFaces 1.1 and added the placeholder for InputSecret with javascript. Not optimal solution, but at least it's there now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing.

I was using Omnifaces to add placeholders to JSF inputFields. I returned to Omnifaces 1.1, who allowed me to add placeholder to < h:inputText>, but not . I don't get the error above with Omnifaces 1.1. I simply used javascript to solve this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            function addPlaceholder() {
                var element = document.getElementById("j_password");
                element.setAttribute("placeholder", "Password");
            }

            window.onload = function() {
                addPlaceholder();
            }
 </script>
```

It does not fix the error above using Omnifaces 1.4/1.5, but it does solve my problem, which was to add a placeholder to < h:inputSecret>.